# Pos Customer Display

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

I tried to implement pos customer display.

1. Installed posbox image on raspberry pi 3
2. Connected printer, then prints ip address.
3. I tried to configure pos customer display using this below link
   https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/step-by-step-guide-for-installing-customer-display-using-posbox-125783
4. Installed hw_customer_display on posbox
5. Installed pos_customer_display on odoo server
6. Configured pos proxy address with posbox ip address (192.168.50.36:8069)

My Odoo instance run on ubuntu 16.04 and client running on windows.

1. Connected customer display on windows machine. But nothing displayed.
2. Connect customer display on posbox, then it displays 'P'. Thats all.
3. Then i remove `hw_scale` from `/root_bypass_ramdisks/etc/init.d/odoo`. and tried again.
   Then the letter `P` disappeared, nothing else.

Any solution?